# layout/default.xml doesn't seem to work in a child theme from Luma

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, parent-child-theme

I have created a new child theme from Luma. The admin panel recognizes that it's registered and I have set it up to be used for my store.

One of the things I tried to achieve was changing the logo for a store, tried to define it in default.xml, and flushed the cache, but nothing changed on the frontend.

Afterward, I tried to insert a container with a block on top of the header, but also no sign of any changes.

What exactly I am doing wrong? Can't seem to figure it out with just the help of Google.

**Files structure**

```
frontend
 ┣ MyVendor
 ┃ ┗ MyTheme
 ┃ ┃ ┣ etc
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ view.xml
 ┃ ┃ ┣ layout
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ default.xml
 ┃ ┃ ┣ templates
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ top_message.phtml
 ┃ ┃ ┣ web
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ css
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ source
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ fonts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ images
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ my_logo.png
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ registration.php
 ┃ ┃ ┗ theme.xml
 ┗ .DS_Store
```

**default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header.message.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-message-wrapper">
                <block name="header.message" template="MyTheme::top_message.phtml" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">
                    images/my_logo.png
                </argument>
                <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">
                    Awesome logo
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

**top_message.phtml**

```
<p>Free shipping for all orders.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the Magento_Theme directory inside your theme.
   frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme
2. Move the layout and templates directory to Magento_Theme.
3. Update the default.xml file like this.

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
    <action method="setLogoFile">
        <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/my_logo.png</argument>
    </action>
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">Awesome logo</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: hah, apparently it was that easy. thank you!